# What is hypothesis testing one sample one sided?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, p-value, pandas

My goal is to learn `hypothesis testing one sample one sided`. Honestly, I don't get it.
Hypothesis testing one sample RIGHT SIDED

```
H0: μ <= x̄
H1: μ > x̄
```

For example, I have a `pg_df = pd.DataFrame([10,9,9,10,11,9,8])`
The `pg_df.mean()` is 9.4
Questions:

1. Google have been saying μ is mean population. But why do we compare it with imaginary mean population e.g `H0: μ <= 15` instead of the actual mean sample e.g `H0: μ <= 9.4`?

```
statistic, pvalue = stats.ttest_1samp(a = pg_df, popmean=15, alternative="greater")statistic, pvalue
```

The p-value is 0.9, which is larger than the significance level of 0.05. Thus, we fail to reject null hypothesis. Which we can conclude that the mean population is lower than 15.

1. If we fail to reject `H0: : μ <= 15`, is the conclusion "the mean population is lower than 15"?

Comment: A couple of comments toward an answer:  a) The test is done against a theoretical mean of 15, because a mean of 15 is meaningful for what is being studied.  For example, maybe the national average is 15, and you want to compare your sample from your population to this national average to see if your population is different.  b)  If you were to accept the null hypothesis, the conclusion would be *mu <= 15*, not that *mu < 15*.  However, by failing to reject the null hypothesis, you don't necessarily accept it.  You just conclude that you don't have sufficient evidence to reject it.  <cont>

Comment: <cont>.  A usual analogy on *c)* is that it is like finding someone *not guilty* of a crime.  It isn't the case that you are saying that they are innocent.  You are just saying that there is not sufficient evidence to conclude that they are guilty.  (In this analogy *not guilty* works like a null hypothesis and *guilty* works like the alternate hypothesis.

Comment: @SalMangiafico `because a mean of 15 is meaningful for what is being studied`. Can I randomly change the pop mean until I get `p-value` below 0.05? By doing so, I can reject the null hypothesis and have enough evidence to use the alternative hypothesis, e.g with `popmean = 10`, let's say the p-value is `0.04`, does it mean I can say, `because the p-value is below 0.05, we have sufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis and conclude that the mean population is above 10` ?

Comment: Well, why would you want to do this ?  ... You could always come up with some hypothesis that would return a significant result.  But there's no point in testing hypotheses that you don't care about.

Comment: Mulling over your question , I'm wondering if your terminology is causing some of the confusion.  With these kind of statistical tests, we assume there is a larger population that we get our sample from.  So in your example you have a sample with an average of 9.4, which is an estimate of the true population mean, which you don't know.  15 could be the mean of a population, but it's not the same population. But in any case, I think it's clearer to think of the 15 as a theoretical mean.  <cont>

Comment: <cont> For example if you had a school class and you are looking at the mean of student grades.  You have the grades, but you are treating them as if they are a sample from a larger population of students that, let's say, might take the class.  There is a true mean grade for that population, but you can't know it.  Let's say you want to compare these data to a theoretical mean of 70 %, because this is the cutoff for a passing grade.  You want to know if you have good evidence that the mean of the population of grades is likely larger than a theoretical passing grade of 70 %.